# How do I get the Java sound API to work from jar

Tags: java, jar, javasound

Now there seems to be a lot of questions about the Java API itself, but I'm facing a problem I haven't found anywhere: My code runs fine if I run it directly from the class file, but it refuses to work as soon as I put it in a JAR.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (Mixer.Info info: mixerInfo) {
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
        Line.Info[] targetLineInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info lineInfo: targetLineInfo) {
            try {
                Line line = mixer.getLine(lineInfo);
                line.open();     //<---- problematic line
                System.out.println("Success: Opened line " + line.getLineInfo());
                if (line.getLineInfo().getLineClass().equals(TargetDataLine.class)) {
                    TargetDataLine dataLine = (TargetDataLine) line;
                    byte[] read = new byte[16];
                    dataLine.start();
                    dataLine.read(read, 0, 16);
                    dataLine.stop();
                    System.out.println("Success: Finished reading from line " + line.getLineInfo());
                }
                line.close();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for this very simple example, the following runs as expected:

```
src>javac AudioTest.java
src>java AudioTest
Success: Finished reading from line interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
Success: Finished reading from line interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
```

Building a jar out of this yields the following result:

```
src>jar cfe AudioTest.jar AudioTest AudioTest.class
src>jar tf AudioTest.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
AudioTest.class
```

The problem arises when trying to run this jar:

```
src>java -jar AudioTest.jar
Error: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
Error: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
```

Running the main class manually and putting the jar on the classpath works as expected.

```
src>java -classpath .\AudioTest.jar AudioTest
Success: Finished reading from line interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
Success: Finished reading from line interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
```

I'm completely stumped at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. I guess your problem must be: the way you build your AudioTest.jar ... but as we have ZERO insight how exactly you do that ... we cant help.

Comment: Please show the entire contents of your .jar file.  You can see the contents with the command `jar tf AudioTest.jar`.

Comment: I stated an observation, and suggested how to improve the question. What exactly is rude about telling you: we cant help you, given the content you provided?

Comment: I was able to load your class into Eclipse IDE and run it. No errors generated. I was able to make a jar, using Eclipse, and run it. No errors generated. The manifest in the jar is virtually identical (I have a couple intervening packages). I assume you are running the jar in the same system. What version of Java are you using? (Grasping at straws.) Maybe try something similar with SourceDataLine as a test? Also, try System.out.printlns for mixer and line info found on system? See at what point engaging AudioSystem fails?

Comment: Maybe try using cfe to have Java generate default manifest instead of cme? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html IDK why that should help, though. Using cfe did work for me. I haven't tried making a manifest an compiling that way.

Comment: I had a bunch more print statements, but I removed them to not overcrowd an already long question. The call to line.open() is the one failing. Using JRE 1.8.0_181, but 1.8.0_221 yields the same behaviour. Autogenerating the JAR makes no difference.